# SQL Add additional column to query result

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a database consisting of two tables. The first is `signals`, the second is called `recordinfo`. I'm first querying the `signals` to find a specific thing.

```
SELECT * 
FROM signals 
WHERE label="mg"
ORDER BY recordid;
```

I want to now add a second column to this query for all found recordids in signal where `label="J"`. Basically add additional data as each row in signals has a seperate id.

Any ideas would be grand!

EDIT:

Seems I wasn't clear enough. Basically there is a table coding for all runs of the experiment labeling them with recordid. The second table contains all the signals but are "tagged" with the corresponding recordid. Now for some runs in addition to the Energy(label="J"), the weights was monitored. But as each signal is a seperate row, it is impossible to just query for all rows containing both "J" and "mg". So I would like to pick out all signals which contain "J" then search for the corresponding "mg" signal in database. The link between these two is the same recordid. The record table doesn't have any important information other than the recordid which is also included in the signal table as a colomun.

So signal has columns:
signalid, signal, recordid, label,time

and record has columns:
record,recordid,date,supervisorid, supervisorname and so on.

Does that make any sense?

I tried querying

```
SELECT * FROM signals WHERE label="mg" 
UNION
SELECT * FROM signals WHERE label="J"
ORDER BY recordid;
```

But that yields also records which don't have both signals. I hope this is clearer now.

Thanks for any help

EXAMPLE:

Here is an excerpt of the signal table and the result of querying for all signals which include unit="J". As I can't post them here is the link: 
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=492B43ABB4BCC7D1!375&authkey=!AOHnPO666zT2Teg&ithint=folder%2cpng

Now I would like to add all the mg data to the query result for which it found a result with unit="J". Hope this clarifies what I'm asking.

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  Your query is returning more than one column.  You mention two tables, neither of which is in the query.  You have two databases tagged.  Try editing the question, adding sample data, and desired results.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Do you want all the records where `label="mg" OR label="J"`?

Comment: What data do you want the second column to contain?

Comment: Post some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Why not use and operator? ?

Comment: And you show some sample data and the result you're trying to get?